# How can gun violence be prevented through policy or action without infringing on the 2nd Amendment?

Tags: united-states, policy, crime, guns

The definition of "infringing on the 2nd Amendment" is highly subjective and a heavy source of debate, so for the scope of this question, let's assume that this means the government cannot prevent law-abiding citizens from obtaining firearms.

What political measures have proven effective around the world at reducing incidents of gun violence?

Comment: What do you mean by "the government cannot prevent law-abiding citizens from obtaining firearms"? What regulations would be allowed under this criteria? Because that's the real question here. Do you mean total deregulation (ie, you can buy an AK-47 at a 7-11)? Are background checks, restrictions on the sale of certain kinds of guns, mandatory licensing and training, and lifetime bans for criminals ok? Because plenty of people would say that some or all of those would be violations of the 2nd Amendment. So you need to define your question more precisely.

Comment: question body and title seem to ask different questions."What political measures have proven effective around the world at reducing incidents of gun violence?" is an answerable question, but added payload of "2nd amendment infringement" makes it opinion based, since even in US there is no definite agreement on what this document was intended to do at the time it was drafted and how should it be treated in modern times.

Comment: How do we prevent nuclear missile violence without infringing on the second amendment? (answer: we don't. we blatantly violate the second amendment to prohibit the private ownership of nuclear missiles)

Answer (score 2):

> What political measures have proven effective around the world at reducing incidents of gun violence?

Infringing on the "rights" of normal people to carry firearms whose primary function is to kill other people seems to work quite well for the rest of the world (sample: [UK](https://www.nationmaster.com/country-info/compare/United-Kingdom/United-States/Crime/Violent-crime), [Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Firearms_Agreement#Effectiveness)). Yes, single-shot hunting rifles can kill people, but they can be used to hunt. Handguns, assault rifles? Not so much.

It is also useful to remember that when the 2nd Amendment got written, a rifle might be reloaded 3 times in a minute by highly skilled, trained, marksmen and frontier people needed to both hunt and contend with potentially hostile Native Americans.

Comment: The article you linked on Australia states that reduction in gun violence coincided with fall of violent crime in general, and that later studies did not show that the legislation was effective in reducing gun-related crime. The link on Britain just shows that Britain has less violent crime than America, not that Britain's gun-related crime was reduced by passing their gun laws. These aren't good sources to support your argument.

Comment: Of course, it can be debated.  Statistical weakness?  Sure.  there are, what, 10-20 countries max with roughly same socio-economic demographics as the US.  stir in a number of variables such as drug & alcohol use, schooling, police competence, legal penalties, ethnicity, urban/rural density, etc... mix it all well and there's no way you're going to get a conclusive **proof**:  there are not enough countries to have a solid statistical comparison.  But ask Joe&Jane Average in Europe, Canada, Japan, Autralia, NZ, etc... if they'd want the US guns laws and on average they'd  (laugh) at you.

Comment: It's not about statistical weakness. You made a statement: "Infringing on the "rights" of normal people to carry firearms whose primary function is to kill other people seems to work quite well for the rest of the world", and supplied two links. Looking at first link, I see that UK has less violence (in general, not just guns) than US. But same site shows, for example, that while Switzerland's gun laws are much less strict than in UK or Russia, yet Swiss violence rates are much lower; so this raw data isn't exactly in support of the argument. It's comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Second link is more relevant, but looking at the "Effectiveness" part (which you cpecifically linked) - the vast majority of studies agree that reduction of violent crime is a part of a greater trend which started before the act was passed, and that act does not seem to significantly contribute to said reduction.

Comment: And re: "ask Joe&Jane Average in Europe, Canada, Japan, Autralia, NZ, etc... if they'd want the US guns laws and on average they'd (laugh) at you". The question is not "choose US or UK gun laws", though? It's "are gun control measures effective at reducing gun violence" (or at least the part of the question that makes sense is). Sure, Joe/Jane Average might go with common-sense opinion that they should be quite effective (because less guns owned means less guns used, right?) - but that's neither what statistics show nor what the asker is interested in.

Comment: Statements like "Britain has less violent crime than America, not that Britain's gun-related crime was reduced by passing their gun laws" neglects the possibility that Britain has less gun crime *because* of gun control. There has been gun legislation in Britain for literally hundreds of years. You think it might not have had an effect? The only alternative is to say that Americans are so batshit crazy that they shoot people ten times more often than other countries just because of who they are, regardless of laws.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov *neither what statistics show* I love how you take refuge behind statistical doubt when we just dont have the sample base (of countries and esp ones wo extra vars) to arrive at any stats-based conclusion.  Nice too, claiming I forgot the unexplained crime drop from 70s on.  Explanations range from leaded gas phaseout, to abortions to boys being raised by WW2-trauma-ed fathers.  I.e. we dont know.  We do know that guns play a unique role in suicides (drop seen in Switzerland after limiting service weapons).  And that no rich country has the freq of mass shooting per cap of the US

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica so what you are saying is that USA is unique and statistics on other countries are not relevant to it? Then why refer to statistics at all in the answer? Why try and answer at all, when you could just frame challenge the question in comments when you voted to close it (i.e. "same political measures *around the world* and *in USA* will have different results, the question is based on false assumption"), instead of answering?

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm positive Britain's gun laws had an effect. The problem is that since they were passed so long ago we don't have much info on how current situation compares to what has been before it was passed, which was the point of the question. And, well, there are examples of countries with gun legislation much more lax than UK's yet with comparable or lower violent crime rates per capita, so yeah, people/culture do matter here.